# Hide Caller ID Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am working on application where I need to hide outgoing call caller ID from my program.android have built-in feature hide caller ID but its not working (it's disable) for some region.can I hide outgoing caller ID programatically ? 
Or I can override android calling screen so the user can't see to whom I am calling ?
Great thanks waiting for ans . . .

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The outgoing caller ID is the user's number. I have a feeling they might already know it.

Comment: Yes but I have this requirement,I don't want to show other people around me they can see my out going number.can say this thing is a part of my application idea.

Comment: I think he means that he doesn't want the number/ID that's being called to be shown on the screen. Which sounds a bit fishy.. why would anyone want to have apps on their phone make outgoing calls to numbers that the user hasn't decided to call him/herself?

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for quick reply , yes I want same thing as you type,but this is my requirement. or I can override calling screen immediately that other people can't see my calling number ?

Comment: It is their phone...You shouldn't be making calls from it if you are unwilling to inform them of who/where they are calling. IMO

Comment: Hi FoamyGuy thanks ,but the thing is that it is featured requirement of my application or you can say my idea main feature . .

Comment: Bad requirements should be rejected.

Comment: Hi Chris Stratton thanks,May be its bad requirement in your understanding but for me assuming this option will make my app good featured app,even app user will be known about this feature ,because main thing is something unique idea may be hard or bad . .-:)p . .hope you understand ,if you can guide the way if it is possible ? Thanks @Chris Stratton

Comment: I did see someone already doing something what I am searching for as describe on this link http://www.hidephonenumbers.com/how-to-hide-your-phone-number-on-a-android-phone

Comment: I think this app also interrupting calling screen for incoming and outgoing also ?                                  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yudiz.autocallaction&feature=search_result