# How to know whether hiding caller id is enabled or not in android?

Tags: android

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510856/how-to-programatically-hide-caller-id-on-android/9839006#9839006) is the indirect solution to enable the hiding of our number i.e. hiding caller ID. But how can I know whether user has enabled to **hide the number** option or not?

I have seen many SO discussions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954046/hide-caller-id-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788205/android-outbound-caller-id-on-off), but none helped me yet.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe there's not a native solution for this. Additionally, I remember that in some previous Android version (I'm currently using `Jelly Bean 4.3`), when I manually turned on the hiding of Caller ID, the calls in the call list appeared to be `#31#XXXXXXXXX`, representing the `#31#` the hiding of the Caller ID.

Seems that in this version it doesn't even appear the prefix, so at least with the above explained you could *statistically infere* if it was turned on or not, but now, I believe there's no way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I will try it. and is there any way to know whether user's country supports hiding caller id? As an example, in America, AFAIK, Networks supports hiding caller ID feature, but in India, Networks don't support this feature...

Comment: The problem of your approach is not just knowing which countries support this feature (which you can get even doing manually with patience knowing one by one), the real problem is knowing in which country the user is. There seems not to be a definitive way to know this, because in what seems to be the most direct way, you'd need to access to the `SIM` card but not every device has one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country